Constructing simple polygon from non-crossing orthogonal line segments
Given a set of $N$ non-crossing orthogonal (vertical and horizontal) line segments on the plane, is there an efficient algorithm to construct a simple orthogonal polygon that passes through all given segments?
All non-crossing segments are internal (endpoint of a segment cannot be a vertex of the polygon). Each side of the orthogonal polygon must contain exactly one internal line segment.
Motivation: Rappaport proved that it is NP-complete to decide whether a set of points in the plane can form simple polygon passing through the given points if 180 degrees angles are allowed at the given points.

